# pushViewController in the method didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uiimagepickercontroller

When i use `pushViewController` i get to a blank view with a navigation button- `Saved photos`, and i don't know why.
I want to move to `ReportViewController` after selecting an image.

this is my code and it seems ok. what can possibly went wrong?

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info{

//Geting the image from the camera
image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

ReportViewController *imageSelectionVC = [[ReportViewController alloc] init];
[imageSelectionVC.imageReport setImage:image];

    [picker pushViewController:imageSelectionVC animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: First dismiss your picker, than push to newviewcontroller.

Comment: push your viewController to your navigationcontroller stack, not to ImagePickerController's stack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as the comments say, you have to dismiss the picker and push the new controller to your animation controller (assuming you have one)

This is the correct code:

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info{
    UIImage* image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
        ReportViewController *imageSelectionVC = [[ReportViewController alloc] init];
        [imageSelectionVC.imageReport setImage:image];

        [self.navigationController pushViewController:imageSelectionVC animated:YES];
    }];
}
```